# Python and Django: How do I dynamically create a dynamic URL with employee ID

Tags: python, django

I have a specific template that can filter an activity logs of an Employee. This is my view:

```
@login_required
def activity_filter(request, buyer_id):
    """Returns activities based on the filter options sent by an (AJAX) POST."""

    template_name = 'buyer/activity/activities.html'

    activities = _compile_activities(request.user.cached_buyer, request.user.cached_buyer_role.privacy_filter)

    year_range = list(range(activities[0].date_created.year, activities[len(activities) - 1].date_created.year - 1, -1))
    form = _ActivitiesFilterForm(
        buyer_id=buyer_id,
        data=request.POST,
        user_choices=_compile_activity_users(activities),
        from_date=activities[len(activities) - 1].date_created,
        to_date=activities[0].date_created,
        from_to_year_range=year_range,
    )

    if not form.is_valid():
        _logger.debug("Filter validation errors: %r", form.errors)
        return render(request, template_name, status=400)
    
    query_params = getattr(request, request.method) # either the request.GET or request.POST dict

    from_date = query_params.get('from_date', None)
    if from_date:
        from_date = datetime.combine(from_date, datetime.min.time())  # first second of the day
        activities = activities.filter(date_created__gte=from_date)

    to_date = query_params.get('to_date', None)
    if to_date:
        to_date = datetime.combine(to_date, datetime.max.time())  # last second of the day
        activities = activities.filter(date_created__lte=to_date)

    selected_users = query_params.getlist('users', None)
    if selected_users:
        user_role_ids, user_role_types = _get_selected_user_role_details(selected_users)
        if user_role_types and user_role_ids:
            activities = activities.filter(user_role_type__in=user_role_types).filter(user_role_id__in=user_role_ids)
    
    if (
        query_params.getlist('users')
    ):
        print("===selected_users===\n", query_params, "\n===selected_users===\n")

    context = {
        'activities': activities[:MAX_NO_OF_ACTIVITIES],
        'activities_search_form': form,
    }

    if is_ajax(request):
        return render(request, 'buyer/activity/activities_table.html', context)
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

[image]

```
<a href="{% url 'buyer:activity' employee.buyer_id %}">
    {% svg_icon "Activity" "w-6 h-6 dui-stroke-primary" None "Latest Activity" %}
</a>
```

[image]

But I need this icon(URL) <a> tag once clicked it will redirect and automatically filtered on my Latest Activity page. I cant figured how to execute it since the return value of my query_params is :

<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['eyrSC8AlXTghbPc692OtSkiAkaKzH5FQgobe3K0CPJYKIgQFgG6Q8NjxdTHymN57'], 'from_date_day': ['25'], 'from_date_month': ['11'], 'from_date_year': ['2015'], 'to_date_day': ['8'], 'to_date_month': ['6'], 'to_date_year': ['2023'], 'users': ['520_12'], 'submit': ['Filter']}>

Thanks in advance! :)

But I need this icon(URL) <a> tag once clicked it will redirect and automatically filtered on my Latest Activity page.

Comment: I can only tell `from_date` and `to_date are `None` since they are not in the query_dict. Thus `activities` are not filtered. Is this the only problem you are facing?

Comment: Hi @EzonZhao it was filtered also, my only problem is I need to make the <a> tag a dynamic URL that will pass a parameter to be filtered once clicked and redirect it to the activity filter page.

Comment: You already have `url` tag supplied with `buyer_id` parameter in your template, which will generate a dynamic url. And the image shows the `url` tag works as expected.

Comment: yes that is working, but I want to add another parameter on my url tag that once clicked it will redirect and filtered automatically on my Latest Activity page.